# Cloudflare returns 403 when different Host header is set

Tags: http-headers, cloudflare, api-gateway

I'm trying to redirect traffic from all services through an API Gateway. To be backward compatible I try to define a CNAME to redirect traffic to the API Gateway. As a result, I have a request coming to the subdomain of my API Gateway but with the `Host` header set to my service subdomain. Something like this: `curl "https://gateway.example.com" -H "Host: myservice.example.com"` Since the domain the and the `Host` are different, Cloudflare (proxied DNS) return 403 HTTP error, hinders the request from reaching the gateway.

Is there any way to relax this restriction while using Cloudflare proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have a look at the [Origin Rules](https://developers.cloudflare.com/rules/origin-rules/) feature? One of the capabilities included allows to override the `Host` header of the incoming proxied request. You could use this to set the correct `Host` header your origin infrastructure is expecting based on the characteristic of the incoming request.

Comment: Thanks. It appears that is sets the rule globally on all records. Is it correct?

Comment: You can scope your rule to match incoming requests based on a formula (same as in Firewall Rules):  https://developers.cloudflare.com/firewall/cf-dashboard/edit-expressions/